# crear y guardar imagen con imagepng php

Tags: php, imagen, fileupload, php8

tengo una función que me recibe la imagen, si cumple con las medidas 500 x 160 ps la conviertes en webp y la guardas y  si no cumple me la redimensiona a esa medida y la guardas, ahora mi problema esta en que  quiero guardar el formato en webp y el formato original, en web y jpg lo guardo sin problema pero el archivo PNG se guarda en 0kb como imagen en blanco, no se que estoy haciendo mal, espero que me puedan ayudar, llevo 2 horas perdidas sin logra ver el problema.

```
  
  function convertImgToWebP_log_pag_Web($img, $nombrearchivo, $quality, $type, $width, $height){

    $nombre_completo_archivo  =  $nombrearchivo;
$parte = explode(".", $nombre_completo_archivo);

    $extImg  = $type;
    $nombreImg = $parte[0];
    
    $nombrearchivo = "$nombreImg.webp";
$listExt = array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png');


    if($width==500 and $height==160){




      
    foreach ($listExt as $ext) {
        if($ext == $extImg){
            switch ($extImg){

                case 'image/jpeg':
                    imagewebp(imagecreatefromjpeg($img),'foto_locales/'.$nombrearchivo, $quality);  
                    imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($img),'foto_locales/'.$nombre_completo_archivo, $quality);
                break;
            case 'image/jpg':
                    imagewebp(imagecreatefromjpeg($img),'foto_locales/'.$nombrearchivo, $quality);
                    imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($img),'foto_locales/'.$nombre_completo_archivo, $quality);
                break;  
            case 'image/png':
                
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($img);
                imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
                imagealphablending($image, true);
                imagesavealpha($image, true);


                    imagewebp($image,'foto_locales/'.$nombrearchivo, $quality);
                    imagepng($image,'foto_locales/'.$nombre_completo_archivo, $quality);

                break;                              
            }   
        }
    }
      
    }else{

        echo "La imagen del logo no cumple con las medidas requeridas, pero fue redimensionada a 500px x 160px<br><br>";



        foreach ($listExt as $ext) {
            if($ext == $extImg){
                switch ($extImg){
    
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                      
                        $im_1024 = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
                        imagepalettetotruecolor($im_1024);
                        imagealphablending( $im_1024, false );
                        imagesavealpha( $im_1024, true );
                        $im_1024 = imagescale($im_1024, 500, 160);
                        imagewebp($im_1024,'foto_locales/'.$nombrearchivo, $quality);   
                        imagejpeg($im_1024,'foto_locales/'.$nombre_completo_archivo, $quality);



                    break;
                case 'image/jpg':
                  
                    $im_1024 = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
                    imagepalettetotruecolor($im_1024);
                    imagealphablending( $im_1024, false );
                    imagesavealpha( $im_1024, true );
                     $im_1024 = imagescale($im_1024, 500, 160);
                        imagewebp($im_1024,'foto_locales/'.$nombrearchivo, $quality);
                        imagejpeg($im_1024,'foto_locales/'.$nombre_completo_archivo, $quality);
                    break;  
                case 'image/png':
              


                    $im_1024 = imagecreatefrompng($img);
                   
                    imagepalettetotruecolor($im_1024);
                    imagealphablending( $im_1024, false );
                    imagesavealpha( $im_1024, true );
                     $im_1024 = imagescale($im_1024, 500, 160);
      
    
                        imagewebp($im_1024, 'foto_locales/'.$nombrearchivo, $quality);
                        imagepng($im_1024,'foto_locales/'.$nombre_completo_archivo, $quality);
                    break;                              
                }   
            }
        }



    }
    return $nombrearchivo;
  }
```

El problema es solamente con los archivos PNG en ambos casos, en jpg y webp me guarda sin problema las imágenes

Comment: ¿Qué dice tu log de errores? Allí debe haber detalles de por qué está fallando el código.

Comment: hola disculpa la demora, me da este error, ya estoy investigando también al respecto por q no había visto el log de errores Warning: imagepng(): gd-png error: compression level must be 0 through 9 in

Comment: listo amigo logre resolver, como que a las png no le puedo colocar como tercer parámetro la calidad, le quite eso y listo ya sube sin problema, gracias.

Comment: *llevo 2 horas perdidas sin logra ver el problema.*... Si hubieras revisado de inmediato el log de errores no habrías perdido tantas horas. Para la próxima, cuando algo falle, vete directo al log de errores, te vas a ahorrar muchas dos horas de ese modo. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.